# Memory allocation for objects in a vector

Tags: c++, stl

I have a structure `coord` and a vector containing objects of type `coord` :

```
struct coord
{
   int x1;
   int x2;
};

vector<coord> v[n];
```

Now when I try to put something(just after vector declaration) into `vector` v using `v[0].x1=2` then compiler gives an error saying

```
'class std::vector<coord, std::allocator<coord> > has no member named x1'
```

but when I use a `temp` object of `coord` type to store coordinates, define vector like

```
vector<coord> v   //i.e without specifying size of vector
```

,push it into vector and then try to access `v[0].x1`, it works fine.

So why I am not able to put into vector using first way but second way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared an array of vectors, not a single vector, so `v[n]` returns a vector.  You should have called the constructor with a `size_t` argument.

```
vector<coord> v(size);
```

Comment: *capacity* and *size* has a different meanings in the context of `std::vector`, and what the `vector<T> (size_type n)` constructor does is create a vector of *size* `n` filled with `n` default-constructed elements. On the other hand, a vector with *capacity* `c` may well contain less than `c` elements. I know you are aware of that and using it as a variable name only but I think in this context it would be good to change it to avoid confusion later.

Comment: @us2012: You're right, it was a sloppy use of the word capacity.  I'll fix it.

Answer (score 4):

To create a vector of size `n` use parentheses, not square brackets.

```
vector<coord> v(n);
```

Using brackets creates an array of `n` vectors rather than a vector with `n` coordinates.